# Android Widget with asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider
 {

    TextView tv;
RemoteViews views;
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        super.onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
        for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
            int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId,views);
            new PostTask().execute("url");

        }
   }

private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];

        // Dummy code

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // connect timeout
        client.setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);    // socket timeout

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "data=something");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .addHeader("postman-token", "7a4d5df8-5aed-19bf-e1fb-c85f821c1d10")
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return e1.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String data = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(result);

            //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("response_data");

            //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("CDRId").toString());
                String name = jsonObject.optString("Status").toString();

                data += "Agent : " + (i + 1) + "\nCDRId : " + id + " \n Status : " + name + " \n ";
            }
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv,data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv,e.toString());
        }


    }
}
```

}

I am trying to get a part of JSON(that I have parsed previously) in a widget. I am using AsyncTask to separate it from main thread and I am using OkHttpClient library to get JSON. I have class PostTask that gets me the parsed JSON. But can please anyone tell me how can I display it in the widget. This is the code.

Comment: In what widget do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: Try to follow Android naming conventions. Your `MainActivity` there is a type of `BroadcastReceiver`, not an `Activity`

Comment: @Vucko I want to display the parsed JSON in any android widget with a textview

Comment: Well that shouldn't be hard, I'm doing such a thing in my app with EventBus. In onPostExecute I dispatch an event and I listen for that event in my activity and change the text accordingly. Google EventBus, it's quite easy to use.

Comment: @Vucko I am newbie to this.....Can you please provide me the code?...That would be easy to understand

Comment: @Vucko Ok I researched that I have add EventBus.getDefault().register(this); and EventBus.getDefault().post(new HelloWorldEvent("Hello EventBus!”); But I am not able to figure out how will these line return a text

Comment: I did provide you with the code, I hope everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom event, something like this:

```
public class MyEvent {
private String text;

public MyEvent(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text= text;
}
```

}

Now at the place where you're posting the Event, simply create this custom Event with the json you want to send to your widget. (put this code in `onPostExecute`).

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MyEvent(result);
```

Now simply wherever your textView is, in Activity or Fragment, register the eventBus in `onCreate`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And create a method that listens for the event like this:

```
@Subscribe
public void onMyEvent(MyEvent myEvent){
    String text = myEvent.getText();
    //Now you can parse this text, if it's JSON, or you can simply set it
    //to your textView or whatever
}
```